# How to assign and execute a custom JavaScript function to a button on InDesgin?

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, javascript

I am new in scripting. 
I have checked other answers and a few tutorials but I failed to find a way to assign custom function to a button on InDesign.

I built a PDF and added a button. I want to import a file on this button click. There is no native option for this in InDesign. 
I thought scripting may be a solution but I don't know its exact usage or how to assign it to the button as I don't see such a option in InDesign CC.

Answer (score 2):

As of the time of posting, it is still impossible to call a custom JavaScript function from InDesign (unfortunately). You need to create the button in ID and then, after the PDF has been exported, use an editor to add that functionality.